# Parameter "triangulatedPoints" of recoverPose and math behind it

Tags: opencv, 3d, linear-algebra, pose-estimation

cv::recoverPose has parameter "triangulatedPoints" as seen in [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga2ee9f187170acece29c5172c2175e7ae), though math behind it is not documented, even in sources [(relevant commit on github)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/8279/files).
When I use it, I get this matrix in following form:

```
[0.06596200907402348, 0.1074107606919504, 0.08120752154556411, 
 0.07162400555712592, 0.1112415181779849, 0.06479560707001968, 
 0.06812069103377787, 0.07274771866295617, 0.1036230973846902, 
 0.07643884790206311, 0.09753859499789987, 0.1050111597547035, 
 0.08431322508162108, 0.08653721971228882, 0.06607013741719928, 
 0.1088621999959361, 0.1079215237863785, 0.07874160849424018, 
 0.07888037486261903, 0.07311940086190356;

 -0.3474319603010109, -0.3492386196164926, -0.3592673043398864,
 -0.3301695131649525, -0.3398606744869519, -0.3240186574427479, 
 -0.3302508442361889, -0.3534091474425142, -0.3134288005980755, 
 -0.3456284001726975, -0.3372514921152191, -0.3229005408417835, 
 -0.3156005118578394, -0.3545418178651592, -0.3427899760859008,  
 -0.3552801904337188, -0.3368860879000375, -0.3268499974874541,
 -0.3221050630233929, -0.3395139819250934;

 -0.9334091581425227, -0.9288726274060354, -0.9277125424980246,
 -0.9392374374147775, -0.9318967835907961, -0.941870018271934,
 -0.9394698966781299, -0.9306592884695234, -0.9419749503870455,
 -0.9332801148509925, -0.9343740431697417, -0.9386198310107222,
 -0.9431781968459053, -0.9290466865633286, -0.9351167772249444,
 -0.9264105322194914, -0.933362882155191, -0.9398254944757025,
 -0.9414486961893244, -0.935785675955617;

 -0.0607238817598344, -0.0607532477465341, -0.06067768097603395,
 -0.06075467523485482, -0.06073245675798231, -0.06078081616640227,
 -0.06074754785132623, -0.0606879948481664, -0.06089198212719162,
 -0.06071522666667255, -0.06076842109618678, -0.06083346023742937,
 -0.06084805655000008, -0.0606931888685702, -0.06071558440082779,
 -0.06073329803512636, -0.06078189449161094, -0.06080195858434526,
 -0.06083228813425822, -0.06073695721101467]
```

e.g. 4x20 matrix (in this case there were 20 points). I want to convert this data to std::vector in order to use it in solvePnP. How to do it, what is the math here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV offers a [`triangulatePoints`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gad3fc9a0c82b08df034234979960b778c) function, which has the same output:

> points4D  4xN array of reconstructed points in homogeneous coordinates.

Which indicates that each column is a 3D point in homogeneous coordinate system. However your points looks quite not as I would expect. For instance your first point is:

```
[0.06596200907402348, -0.3474319603010109, -0.9334091581425227, -0.0607238817598344]
```

But I would expect the last component to be 1.0 already. You should double check if something is not wrong here. You can always remove the "scaling" of the point by dividing each dimension by the last component:

```
 [ x, y z, w ] = w [x/w, y/w, z/w, 1]
```

And then use the first three parts for your PnP solution.

I hope this helps

Comment: The thing is that I have only one camera and not stereo pair, is this function (triangulatePoints) can be used with one camera?

Comment: @stackoverflower there is no difference if you use the same camera with two images taken from slightly different point of view with overlapping field of view... it is almost as taking 1 image from 2 different cameras... However don't expect it to work for more than 2 images... it will be like having 3 or more cameras and not 2...